# Git hangs after writing objects, when i am trying to push my ios app

Tags: ios, git

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 865, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (766/766), done.
Writing objects: 100% (865/865), 67.02 MiB | 7.63 MiB/s, done.
Total 865 (delta 237), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the size of your `postBuffer` in your global `.gitconfig` file.

Add this line to `.gitconfig`:

```
[http]
    postBuffer = 524288000
```

You can adjust the `postBuffer` of course.